# Checking if method was invoked with specific arguements only once with mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I'm using Mockito in kotlin to check that a list is paged correctly

I use this code

```
    logic.searchItems(filter)
    verify(vm).setItems(all.subList(0, 10), true)
    logic.loadNext()
    verify(vm).setItems(all.subList(0, 20), true)     (1)
    logic.loadNext()
    verify(vm).setItems(all.subList(0, 30), true)     (2)
```

In theory this should work, but I get too many invocations exception in (1) and (2).

If I use times(1) in (1) and times(2) in (2) the test passes. But I wish to verify that that method is called with those specific arguments.

Can this be done with Mockito?

Answer (score 1):

After some testing I figured out that the problem was that in my logic I added the results to the same list before sending them back like so:

```
addItems(results:List<Item>()){
    //verifications here
    myItems.addAll(results)
    vm.setItems(myItems,true)
}
```

this for some reason made mockito think it was the same invocation?

when I do it like this it works

```
addItems(results:List<Item>()){
    //verifications here
    myItems.addAll(results)
    vm.setItems(myItems.map { it.copy() },true)
}
```

I do not know if it is a bug, or the intended behaviour, but at least this works

edit:

Ok so I feel like an idiot because it is not a bug at all, it is indeed the intended behaviour, and it saved me some future trouble

when using captors, I figured out that when the `setItems` method is called Mockito keeps a reference to the returned list.

the next time it is called I used to add items to myItems and Mockito kept the new reference

but since I performed an `addAll` operation the reference that was previously kept also got updated, so it is indeed normal that Mockito needs the times(2) method when I call it because the list it got in the first invocation was updated and will match the second list.

the correct way it seems, is to send a copy of that list, that way the viewModel can't alter the original list in any way

Answer (score 0):

With this kind of parameters, being a Collection with specific content I would advise using the `ArgumentCaptor` feature. Thanks to that you will be able to capture the passed parameters and later assert their value / state using tools like Hamcrest or AssertJ:

```
final ArgumentCaptor<List> captorListOne = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(List.class);
final ArgumentCaptor<List> captorListTwo = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(List.class);
final ArgumentCaptor<List> captorListThree = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(List.class);

verify(vm).setItems(captorListOne.capture(), true)
logic.loadNext()
verify(vm).setItems(captorListTwo.capture(), true)     
logic.loadNext()
verify(vm).setItems(captorListThree.capture(), true) 

List listToAssert = captorListOne.getValue();
...
```

More the [ArgumentCaptor](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.6.9/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html)

Comment: That seems like a good idea, I usually only use captors when I don't know what the result will be and want to verify some parts, thanks

Comment: Those sublist params that are expected just look like ones that may cause problems during verification. With captor you can assert any way you like